# Passing a lambda to a template function taking a std::function as parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, lambda

I have a template function taking a `std::function` parameter, the template arguments defining function signature:

```
template<typename... Args>
void addController(const char * name, const std::function<bool(Args...)> & func);
```

It works passing a `std::function` variable:

```
std::function<bool()> foo_func = [this]()->bool {return this->isFoo(); };
addController<>("foo", foo_func);  //Works
```

But if I pass the lambda directly, it fails deducing the type:

```
//Fails to compile
addController<>("foo", [this]()->bool {return this->isFoo(); });
```

And using a non template function works:

```
void addControllerNoArg(const char * name, std::function<bool()> func);
addControllerNoArg("foo", [this]() {return this->isFoo(); });  //Works
```

I need the <typename... Args> template for unwrapping a variant vector argument tables into the function call. This actually does work in the implementation, the only issue is I can't pass a lambda to addController directly.

Minimal example:
https://onlinegdb.com/MS1cEreKhk

Comment: `template <typename FunctionType> void addControler(F f);`. Don't confuse `std::function` to be the goto type whenever you need to pass around a callable. You need it for type erasure, ie when you need one object that can store all kinds of callables

Comment: I need <typename... Args> because internally, arguments are retrieved in a variant table that needs to be unwrapped into func call

Comment: Added a minimal example but there isn't more inside than what shown above

Comment: `#includes` and the context for `this` is a lot, when someone else wants to either reproduce your error or test their answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Way to go is generic callable:

```
template<typename F>
void addController(const char* name, F f)
```

You can forward it to your `std::function` version if needed:

```
template <typename... Args>
void addController(const char* name, const std::function<bool(Args...)> & func)
{
   /*..*/
}

template <typename F>
void addController(const char* name, F f)
{
    addController(name, std::function{f}); // CTAD used, so C++17 required
}
```

Comment: Yeah overloads :)

Comment: I've tested this, but it says missing template arguments before {f} https://onlinegdb.com/3dSMUCSYvG

Comment: @galinette You need to compile with C++17 or newer.

Comment: @galinette That compiler doesn't seem to enable C++17 by default. It works here: https://godbolt.org/z/Y6G43fd9n